# Using custom CIFilter on CALayer shows no change to CALayer

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, calayer, cifilter

We are trying to create a custom `CIFilter` to add on top of our `CALayer's.` How ever only the default CIFilters seem to work on a `CALayer.`

We created a small new project on the `ViewController.swift` we added:

```swift
import Cocoa
import CoreImage

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create some layers to work with! (square with gradient color)
        let mainLayer = CALayer()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [NSColor.red.cgColor, NSColor.white.cgColor, NSColor.yellow.cgColor, NSColor.black.cgColor]
        
        shapeLayer.path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500), transform: nil)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = CGColor.black
        
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer
        
        gradientLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))
        mainLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        
        mainLayer.filters = []
        self.view.layer?.addSublayer(mainLayer)

        // Register the custom filter
        CustomFilterRegister.register()
        
        // Test with a normal image file, WORKS!
//      if let image = NSImage(named: "test"), let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil) {
//          if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter") {
//              filter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
//              let output = filter.outputImage
//              // WORKS! Image filtered as expected!
//          }
//      }
        
        // Does NOT work. No change in color of the layer!
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter") {
            filter.name = "custom"
            mainLayer.filters?.append(filter)
        }

        // This works: mainLayer and sublayers are blurred!
//      if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") {
//          filter.name = "blur"
//          mainLayer.filters?.append(filter)
//      }


    }
}
}
```

We created a simple custom `CIFilter` to give it a first try before we start building our custom `CIFilter.`

```swift
class CustomFilter: CIFilter {
    
    // Error in xcode if you don't add this in!
    override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return true
    }
        
    @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?
    @objc dynamic var inputSaturation: CGFloat = 1
    @objc dynamic var inputBrightness: CGFloat = 0
    @objc dynamic var inputContrast: CGFloat = 1
    override func setDefaults() {
        inputSaturation = 1
        inputBrightness = 0
        inputContrast = 2
    }
    
    override public var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let image = inputImage else {
            return nil
        }
        return image.applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectProcess")
            .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [
                kCIInputSaturationKey: inputSaturation,
                kCIInputBrightnessKey: inputBrightness,
                kCIInputContrastKey: inputContrast
            ])
    }
}

class CustomFilterRegister: CIFilterConstructor {
    static func register() {
        CIFilter.registerName(
            "CustomFilter", constructor: CustomFilterRegister(),
            classAttributes: [
                kCIAttributeFilterCategories: [kCICategoryBlur, kCICategoryVideo, kCICategoryStillImage]
            ])
    }
    func filter(withName name: String) -> CIFilter? {
        switch name {
        case "CustomFilter":
            return CustomFilter()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewController we added code to test with a normal image. This DOES work so the filter seems to be ok. We also tried a default `CIGaussianBlur` and that does work on the `CALayer.`

We are lost as to what is needed to get a custom `CIFilter` working with `CALayer,` and can't seem to find any information on it.

Please note that we are NOT looking for this type of `CIFilter` or a different way to get the filters result. We need a custom `CIFilter` to work on a `CALayer.`

Comment: Possible dumb question, but just trying to help. You've tagged this [macos]. There are many differences - and NO, I am not qualified to state them - between CoreImage on iOS and macOS. Any chance your code works in iOS?

Comment: @dfd you can't attach filters to layers in iOS, so the OP's code is certain to fail on iOS devices.

Comment: As I said, a possibly dumb question

Comment: Indeed macOS tagged for a reason . 

And as the code states the built in CIFilter does work when called directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DonMag points out it should have worked with the changes he described. How ever unfortunately we heard back from Apple today;

At this time, there is a bug preventing custom CIFilters on a CALayer from working.  There is no workaround for this bug at this time.

When we file the bug I will add the link here for those interested. But at this time you can not add a custom CIFilter to a CALayer on macOS 11.

Let’s hope they fix it for all of you reading this for a solution.

---

**EDIT**:

So bad news... currently on macOS 12.2.1, and it still has the same issue, nothing has happened based on our ticket. Doesn't seem like Apple want's to fix this. For those of you out there looking: This still does NOT work on a `CALayer` even with all the options on like described in the other answers. A builtin `CIFilter` works as expected.

Note that using the same custom `CIFilter` on a `CALayer` for an export using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` does work!

Comment: Absolute disappointment. First, we try something on a secondary display for our project in a planetarium dome, with time and resources taken to organise the trip and the time to do the tests, the hdmi connection, optical display connection and other various methods we tried fail. Then we find out from a reddit thread that mac os monterey broke the external display feature, quite crucial to be honest. And now this, after spending 3 or more hours testing with various methods and default filters, thinking I got something wrong in the shader I wrote. Seriously?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have done this somewhere not shown in your code:

```
self.view.wantsLayer = true
```

but you'll also want to do this:

```
self.view.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true
```

Result ***without*** that line:

[image]

Result ***with*** that line:

[image]

(Don't ask me why "CIGaussianBlur" works anyway...)

---

**Edit** - the exact code I used to produce the above output:

```
import CoreImage

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true
        
        // Create some layers to work with! (square with gradient color)
        let mainLayer = CALayer()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [NSColor.red.cgColor, NSColor.white.cgColor, NSColor.yellow.cgColor, NSColor.black.cgColor]
        
        shapeLayer.path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500), transform: nil)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = CGColor.black
        
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer
        
        gradientLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))
        mainLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        
        mainLayer.filters = []
        self.view.layer?.addSublayer(mainLayer)

        // Register the custom filter
        CustomFilterRegister.register()
        
        let t = 2
        
        if t == 1 {
            // Test with a normal image file, WORKS!
            if let image = NSImage(named: "test"), let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil) {
                if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter") {
                    filter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                    let output = filter.outputImage
                    // WORKS! Image filtered as expected!
                    print()
                }
            }
        }
        
        else if t == 2 {
            // 
            // Does NOT work. No change in color of the layer!
            // 
            // This NOW works for me
            // 
            if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CustomFilter") {
                filter.name = "custom"
                mainLayer.filters?.append(filter)
            }
            
        } else {
            
            // This works: mainLayer and sublayers are blurred!
            if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") {
                filter.name = "blur"
                mainLayer.filters?.append(filter)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

class CustomFilter: CIFilter {
    
    // Error in xcode if you don't add this in!
    override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?
    @objc dynamic var inputSaturation: CGFloat = 1
    @objc dynamic var inputBrightness: CGFloat = 0
    @objc dynamic var inputContrast: CGFloat = 1
    override func setDefaults() {
        inputSaturation = 1
        inputBrightness = 0
        inputContrast = 2
    }
    
    override public var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let image = inputImage else {
            return nil
        }
        return image.applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectProcess")
            .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [
                kCIInputSaturationKey: inputSaturation,
                kCIInputBrightnessKey: inputBrightness,
                kCIInputContrastKey: inputContrast
            ])
    }
}

class CustomFilterRegister: CIFilterConstructor {
    static func register() {
        CIFilter.registerName(
            "CustomFilter", constructor: CustomFilterRegister(),
            classAttributes: [
                kCIAttributeFilterCategories: [kCICategoryBlur, kCICategoryVideo, kCICategoryStillImage]
            ])
    }
    func filter(withName name: String) -> CIFilter? {
        switch name {
        case "CustomFilter":
            return CustomFilter()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Curiously, if I add a counter var and `print()` statements like this:

```
var applyCount: Int = 0

override public var outputImage: CIImage? {
    print("getting outputImage...")
    guard let image = inputImage else {
        return nil
    }
    applyCount += 1
    print("apply", applyCount)
    return image.applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectProcess")
        .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [
            kCIInputSaturationKey: inputSaturation,
            kCIInputBrightnessKey: inputBrightness,
            kCIInputContrastKey: inputContrast
        ])
}
```

On macOS 10.15.4 / Xcode 12.4, I get this in debug console:

```
getting outputImage...
apply 1
getting outputImage...
apply 2
getting outputImage...
apply 3
getting outputImage...
apply 4
getting outputImage...
apply 5
getting outputImage...
apply 6
getting outputImage...
apply 7
getting outputImage...
apply 8
getting outputImage...
apply 9
getting outputImage...
apply 10
getting outputImage...
apply 11
getting outputImage...
apply 12
getting outputImage...
apply 13
getting outputImage...
apply 14
getting outputImage...
apply 15
getting outputImage...
apply 16
```

(and it continues to get called repeatedly when the window changes size, for example).

However, running on macOS 11.4 / Xcode 12.5.1, I get ***nothing*** in the debug console... `outputImage` is never requested?

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever actually attached a CI filter to a layer on Mac OS (I work mostly on iOS these days.) Why in heaven's name do you have to explicitly set a flag layerUsesCoreImageFilters, when the layer has an Optional `filters` property that defaults to nil, and you have to explicitly set to an array of filters? Seems needlessly complex. It would take like 3 lines of code in the framework to set that property based on setting the filters property to non-nil.

Comment: @DuncanC - I agree, although it's *possible* there is a reason... I don't even do any MacOS development - it just looked like an interesting question, so I took a quick crack at it :)

Comment: I guess the reason is that Core Animation layers are lower-level than views, and cross-platform. A CALayer doesn't necessarily know if it is the backing layer of a view (NSView or UIView) or not. It would require a little fancy footwork to make an NSView observe changes to the `filters` property of it's backing layer (Assuming `wantsLayer` is true, that is...)

Comment: You are correct. 

self.view.wantsLayer = true 

We set that in the storyboard for the view. How ever with or without the line

self.view.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true

The custom CIFilter still does not work. I don't see any differences when running our example project with or without that code.

The question remains... why does a default CIFilter work and a custom one does not. We have also requested code level support from Apple. But so far no response (WWDC might make that even a longer wait that normal)

Thanks for giving it a try.. but not the solution for us I'm afraid.

Comment: @JorydeKort - hmmm? *"The custom CIFilter still does not work"*? I edited my answer with the exact code I used to confirm that it worked for me...

Comment: @DonMag so now it get's really interesting.... when I copy and paste your code (even into a new project), no joy on my end.... What macOS are you running? And what Xcode? I'm trying on M1 with macOS 11.4 and Intel with macOS 11.5 beta 3 and both on Xcode 11.4. But I can't get the custom filter to work.

Comment: @JorydeKort - not sure what to tell you... I'm running 10.15.4 on an Intel Mac mini (2018) Xcode 12.4

Comment: @DonMag I will have to check on macOS 10.15 and see if that works. We did a code level support request to Apple... but still nothing back. Not sure I should mark as the right answer since I haven't been able to confirm yet. Oh and on Xcode 12.4 (12.5 now). Getting lost in all the version numbers that are so close ;)

Comment: @JorydeKort - OK - I updated a different system to macOS 11.4 / Xcode 12.5.1 and I'm seeing the same result as you (that is, the Custom Filter fails to modify the layer). *Something has changed....*

Comment: @JorydeKort - I edited my answer with another observation. It doesn't give me any help figuring it out though.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag... I just got a reply from Apple Support that they are looking in to it and will get back to me asap... I will keep you posted. And share what they say. It's good to know it used to work. Let's hope it will work again some day soon.

Comment: Well just heard back from Apple: At this time, there is a bug preventing custom CIFilters on a CALayer from working.  There is no workaround for this bug at this time.